# Tabular - 3 columns with top-align and bottom-align

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{center}

    \begin{tabular}{cp{7.5cm}p{2.4cm}}

        \textbf{L4} &
        For a sound explanation of both budget lines and indifference curves and a clear link to the separate demand curve, sound explanation of link between utility, price and demand, with accurate clear diagrams and a clear understanding of the principles involved. 
        &\textbf{[9--12]}\\
    \end{tabular}

\end{center}


\end{document}
```

With this code, the rightmost and leftmost columns have their text aligned to the top.

I would like the rightmost column (L4) to be aligned top, and the leftmost ([9--12]) to be aligned bottom.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I've tried using m, b, and p - didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that I did was to add `&\\[-\normalbaselineskip]&` between the 2nd and last columns on every row.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{center}

    \begin{tabular}{cp{7.5cm}p{2.4cm}}

        \textbf{L4} & 
        For a sound explanation of both budget lines and indifference curves and a clear link to the separate demand curve, sound explanation of link between utility, price and demand, with accurate clear diagrams and a clear understanding of the principles involved. 
        &\\[-\normalbaselineskip]&
        &\textbf{[9--12]}\\
        \textbf{L4} & 
        For a sound explanation of both budget lines and indifference curves and a clear link to the separate demand curve, sound explanation of link between utility, price and demand, with accurate clear diagrams and a clear understanding of the principles involved. 
        &\\[-\normalbaselineskip]&
        &\textbf{[9--12]}\\
    \end{tabular}

\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

This can be codified in macro form (though it is particular to a 3-column `tabular`.  Here, `\lastbit{}` is the macro:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\def\lastbit#1{\\[-\arraystretch\normalbaselineskip]&&\textbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{center}

    \begin{tabular}{cp{7.5cm}p{2.4cm}}

        \textbf{L4} & 
        For a sound explanation of both budget lines and indifference curves and a clear link to the separate demand curve, sound explanation of link between utility, price and demand, with accurate clear diagrams and a clear understanding of the principles involved. 
        &\lastbit{[9--12]}\\
        \textbf{L4} & 
        For a sound explanation of both budget lines and indifference curves and a clear link to the separate demand curve, sound explanation of link between utility, price and demand, with accurate clear diagrams and a clear understanding of the principles involved. 
        &\lastbit{[9--12]}\\
    \end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is pretty genius - I wasn't aware of this baselineskip! 
Also - it does seem very weird to me that tabular cannot have columns independently aligned as desired.

Comment: @TheveshTheva I had to use `\normalbaselineskip`, as `\baselineskip` is set to 0pt by the `tabular` environment.  If you any `\arraystretch` active, there would require further modification.  Alignment is a tricky thing, when you consider it has to account for letter descenders, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{collcell}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{B}{>{\collectcell{\Block[B]{}}}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}cp{7.5cm}>{\bfseries}B}
L4 
& For a sound explanation of both budget lines and indifference curves and a clear link to the separate demand
curve, sound explanation of link between utility, price and demand, with accurate clear diagrams
and a clear understanding of the principles involved.  
& [9--12] \\
L4 
& For a sound explanation of both budget lines and indifference curves and a clear link to the separate demand
curve, sound explanation of link between utility, price and demand, with accurate clear diagrams and
a clear understanding of the principles involved.  
& [9--12] \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]